# SSRS cannot figure out Specify a valid URL error

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I was creating a report but I seem to have made a mistake somewhere. 
Whenever I try to run my report, I get "An error occurred... Specify a valid URL. Report URLs may use only http://..."

I narrowed it down to the 3 text boxes that are causing me this problem (as in if I delete these text boxes, the report runs normally.) These were text boxes that I have a click action taking it to another report. I've inspected these textboxes in every possible way and I do not see what is causing it to say invalid URL. Nowhere am I specifying a URL. I do have it go to a different report on click action, but not to a URL...

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas?

EDIT: When I change the action from Go to report to None, it works which strange since there is nothing about a URL. The most confusing part is that I have other text boxes that do this exact same thing where if you click on them, it will go to that same exact report. I cannot figure out why those work and these don't.

Comment: A action to go to a different report, when viewing the report, will be resolved into a hyperlink. I suspect the problem is in your of your parameters. At a guess.

Comment: I also think it is a paramter since I have other text boxes that go to that exact same report and they work fine, I just can't figure out what is wrong with these as they use pretty much exactly the same parameters.

Comment: @nathan can you hard code the values for your sub-reports / action reports and does those action reports run fine? I've had issues like that in past with formatting of how data param was being passed to sub-report. Phase 2: try to try is just put text boxes on subreport and see what values these params display (remove the dataset for query/proc)